# What is the concept of raising and lowering matrices called?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I recently learned I can represent addition of a number to a specific row in a vector by transforming it into a one dimension higher, multiplying it by a square matrix that denotes the addition, then transforming it back into the one lower dimension.

eg

I can represent [0] + [5] = [5] by projecting 0 into a 2d vector

$$
\left[\begin{array}{l}
0\\
1
\end{array}\right]
$$

and 5 into a special 2x2 matrix representing the addition Monoid($\lambda x. x + 5$); effectively transforming 0 + 5 into ($\lambda x. x + 5$) 0.

$$
\left[\begin{array}{ll}
0 & 5\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$

getting the following expression

$$
\left[\begin{array}{ll}
0 & 5\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
*
\left[\begin{array}{l}
0\\
1
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{l}
5\\
1
\end{array}\right]
$$

but then I need to somehow project it down from 2d vector to a 1d vector(scalar).

What is the name for these "raising" and "projection" transformations and can they be represented in the matrix algebra alone(eg matrix multiplication of some sort)?

They have this strange feel of free and forgetful functors(one gaining structure for free, other losing structure), but in a way I can't express.

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ can be identified with $\begin{bmatrix} x & y \end{bmatrix} \mapsto 5x+y$, so I guess you want to plug in $x=1,y=0$? Then the overall thing is $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 5 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = 5$.

Comment: not sure what you mean; I'm doing a literal expression so no variables are needed.

Comment: The variables were just a way to express the idea of identifying $\begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ as a linear functional acting on row vectors. With that idea in hand we can forget about the variables; at the end of the day I think the matrix product I wrote provides a "matrix multiplication implementation" of $0+5$ in the way that you want. I can't be quite certain because I don't really know why you want to do this anyway.

Comment: the matrix is the implementation is the square matrix; there are lambdas and multiplication implied by our algebra; [1 0; 0 1] is the same thing as \A. [1 0; 0 1] [A_0, A_1]

Comment: Sure, but if you want to make that square matrix represent a mapping that returns a *scalar* then you need to identify it not with a *linear transformation* but with a *bilinear form*, i.e. with the bilinear form $B(x,y)=x^T \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 5 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} y$. Then $x=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},y=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ results in the particular sum you want. I think I am not understanding the point, however.

Comment: I'll do some reading on bilinear form for now, I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: @Ian I think he's talking about using homogeneous coordinates to represent affine transformations as linear.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom That is another possibility, probably more likely than my proposal.

Answer (score 1):

In computer graphics this is called using [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates#Use_in_computer_graphics).

The usual coordinates are called the *affine part*.

Comment: but what are the two projections called? clearly they are not equivalent so it's invalid to just move from the R object to R^2 object; I'd understand if it moved it but the second row being 0, but mine turns to 1, effectively making something from nothing, which is illegal without moving to a new system while working with the new object and then using the second transformation to get R back, but even then it is effectively a side effect.

Comment: @Dmitry you're not really adding any information to your object.  Really, you're just lifting a point in $\Bbb R$ (which we traditionally identify as the $x$-axis in $\Bbb R^2$) to the line $y = 1$ in $\Bbb R^2 = \{(x,y) : x,y \in \Bbb R^2\}$.  The "projections", as you call them, are just called conversions to/from homogeneous coordinates.

Comment: @Dmitry I'm not really sure if that answers your question, though since I'm not quite sure what you mean: *I'd understand if it moved it but the second row being 0, but mine turns to 1, effectively making something from nothing(?), which is illegal without moving to a new system(?) while working with the new object and then using the second transformation to get R back(??), but even then it is effectively a side effect.*

Comment: @omnomnomnom the transformation makes no sense from 2d perspective since it does not preserve equality; by performing the operation in the new "homogenous space" we can't return to 1d space without having preformed a miracle in 1d space, since there are no objects in any space that can be applied on 0 to obtain a nonzero value. However I think I understand what you are saying, we implicitly assert that we are transforming our space into a space where 2 and [2, x] are equivalent and that projection is not isomorphic, as there is no way of recovering uniquely the object in R.

Comment: basically, I am concerned what the morphisms that send an object from R to homogenous R and back. It seems that it's possible to go into homogenous space, but not backwards as the honest representation of this is that if it is allowed to return to R we destroy our deductive system, making everything equivalent(unless we explicitly keep the transformation to homogenous space to prevent multiplication on the object).

Comment: @Dmitry it's starting to sound like you should make a new question about just this point that you're trying to resolve.  In any case, I still don't really understand your objection.  For a vector $\mathbf x = (x_1,\dots,x_n)\in \Bbb R^n$, the process looks like this:
$$
\mathbf x = (x_1,\dots,x_n) \mapsto (x_1,\dots,x_n,1) = (\mathbf x,1) \mapsto \mathbf(A \mathbf x + \mathbf b,1) \mapsto A \mathbf x + \mathbf b
$$
And that second map can be done with matrix multiplication.  So, what part of this process is suspicious?

Comment: Perhaps your objection is that $(x_1,\dots,x_n) \mapsto (x_1,\dots,x_n,1)$ **is not a linear map**.  Is **this** what you're trying to say?

Comment: I'm not sure; I don't know enough about the conversion to/from homogenous coordinates maps; I'm sure that they are maps; they just feel very unnatural; it's hard to convince myself that mapping 1 to [1;0] adds no information. That said the question was what the maps were called; you said they are conversations from/to homogenous coordinates and there is no way to describe these maps using linear maps. Is this correct?

Comment: **Conversions**. I don't know if that is the official term, but I don't think there *is* and official term. But besides that, yes.